# How to connect ESP32 to HC-06?

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, hc-06

I am making a small project (BT controlled "tank") and need to connect ESP32 with HC-06 (ESP32 will be in controller and HC-06 in the vehicle). Android phone communication with both ESP and HC-06 works prefectly, I can not just figure out, how to pair/connect these two modules. Any ideas?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I can not connect them, because the HC-06 has PIN and I can not figure out how to remove that PIN or connect to it with PIN from ESP32...

Comment: The HC-06 can just communicate over the SPP protocol (UART/Serial). Your phone (it isn't an iPhone, as it is not able to use this protocol) can search for this service. So, you have to set a GATT server or client and search for a characteristics with the SPP GUID (you can find something here: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html). It isn't so easy and you are very limited. Why not use directly 2 ESP32 with ESP NOW for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a breadboard Or Female to Female Jumber wires.

Ofoucrse you can always solder yourself the two modules together with wires.

PS. Too low reputation to comment, so i insert this as answer

Comment: Yeah, I know that my question was a bit unclear, I meant connect / pair WITH BLUETOOTH, but thanks anyways.. :)